# C# Does list hold a reference to the element after adding it or creates a copy?

Tags: c#, list, reference-type

Let's assume I have an object added to list on creation, does it create a copy of the object in a list or does it create new object, please consider the following code:

```
var obj = new A();
obj.Prop = 10;
var list = new List<A>() { obj };
foreach (var l in list) {
  l.Prop = 20;
}
Console.WriteLine(obj.Prop);
```

What will be printed out to console?

Comment: Can I interest you in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to answer such questions immediately? (Well, almost immediately -- you still need to add `class A { public int Prop { get; set; } }`, but that's not much of a burden.)

Comment: If it's a reference type, then it's just a reference. If it's a value type, then it's a copy.

Comment: "What will be printed out to console?" Just test it

Comment: @JeroenMostert not that fast, and what if A would be a struct and not class?

Comment: Then LINQPad would give you the opportunity to learn even more about C#, because it will tell you that the code is now illegal -- you can't change members of value types used as `foreach` variables. Yes, if you need authoritative answers and in-depth explanations, you need the language specification, merely running some code won't do. But anything of the form "what's this particular piece of code going to print to the console" should arguably first just be tried, and then you can think about explaining the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes and & no.

The list will contain a copy - but of the reference. So it will point to the same object in memory. Unless you assign a reference to a different object or null at any of those variables, they will continue to point to the same thing.

To avoid this, you usually have to go [into cloning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_(programming)). Unlike Java there is no Framework function for it.

There are two cases where you do not need to clone:

1. Builtin Primitive types
2. The buildin string type (despite being a reference type)

Builtin Primitive types have their value copied to a new place in memory.*

String in turn is inmutable by design. It is a rare property for a class, as you would be hard pressed to even find a dozen Inmutables in the entire .NET Framework. But in user defined classes it can be a lot more likely.

For self-made structs, you are even *encouraged* to make the immutable too.

*Unless the JiT and compiler Optimisations decide that it seems underused and thus can be cut out.

Comment: "Unlike Java there is no Framework function for it" That´s why there is an `IClonable`-interface.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I looked it up, and ICloneable is from the pre-generic age. IIRC, the Java side function will actually have the proper return type (Edit: Okay, I was defintely wrong with that. I wonder with what languge I mixed that up). But IClonable.Clone() will give you an object, so it is not very typesafe. And I do love compile time type safety.

Comment: If you use Automapper you can clone the actual objects without any extra effort. You have to create a map configuration that has the same source and destination type. I have also used DeepCloner before for cloning objects

Comment: @pantonis: AutoMapper is wierd. For me all the examples look as if someone just messed up basic inheritance. And it *has* to work with Reflection. Wich I dislike for the same reason as I dislike Object as argument or return value.

Answer (score 0):

> does it create a copy of the object in a list or does it create new object

As you are talking about reference types, the object is the same one, just a reference is made to it and if you change the state of the object somehow, it will reflect in the list as well, as both are pointing to the same object.

`obj` and the item added in the list `new List<A>() { obj };` are both pointing to the same memory location as it's a reference type. So, no new object is actually created. A copy of reference is created and both are holding reference to the same one.